# Design problem: fetching more data for some of the records I retrieve in an sql query

Tags: mysql, design-patterns

Say I have a query that fetches [type][show_name].
For all [type]==5 records, I need to join them with another table.

What would be the best approach for that:

1. Join for all records between the two tables (looks bad).
2. Run the query and then run again on the result set, fetch all the IDs and do a IN query on the table I need to join with.
3. Fetch the missing data only after what I have is presented (using the same IN query), maybe with an AJAX approach.
4. Something I haven't thought of.

Important thing is, I want the user to see at least some of the data as fast as possible, but I also want the code to be straight forward, without too much spaghetti.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do a `left join` and put the `type=5` clause inside the join condition. This will return you `null` in the other table if the `type` isn't 5.

```
select
    a.type,
    a.show_name,
    b.whatever
from
    tableA a
    left outer join tableB b on
        a.id = b.id
        and a.type = 5
```

This works because it only joins the records with `type=5`. If you were to put `a.type=5` inside the `where` clause, it would limit your result set to those where `type=5`.

Comment: Should the a.type = 5 condition be before the a.id = b.id condition, or it does not matter?

Comment: doesn't matter, x and y being exactly the same as y and x.